# jquery .when not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback

I need to inject videos and images into some html content, but only once that html content has finished being loaded. this is my code:

```
function loadMacBook() {
    $('.apple_device').load('html/macbook.html');
}

function browser() {
    $('.slider').load('html/browser-3.html');
}

function portfolioData_1() {

    $('.specifics.data-4 span').text('Sass, HTML, Adobe Suite');
    $.when(loadMacBook()).done(function() {
        $('video').prepend('<source src="assets/shoot-case-study/shoot.mp4" type="video/mp4">');
    });

    $.when(browser()).done(function() {
        $('.browser.data-1 .browser_content').prepend('<img src="assets/shoot-case-study/shoot-1.png" />');
}
```

However it is not working as intended, the function that loads html doesn't wait to be finished before loading the images/videos, therefore half the time the images are loaded before the html even exists and it bugs.

I understand that I need to callback or use promises, but don't quite understand how to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load` does not return a promise. It returns a jQuery object onto which additional methods can be chained.

Even if `load` did return a promise, you're not returning it from your two functions.

You need to pass callbacks into your functions, so you can pass those callbacks into `load`:

```
function loadMacBook(callback) {
  $('.apple_device').load('html/macbook.html', callback);
}

...

loadMacBook(function () {
  $('video').prepend(...);
});
```

Also note that there is absolutely no need for `when` in your question. You're misusing it in both cases. You do not need to **rewrap** a promise in `when` in order to invoke `then` or `done`, on it, just *invoke them directly on the promise itself*. If your function returned a promise, the correct way to use it would simply be:

```
loadMackBook().done(function () { ... });
```

Comment: I should probably do some research on promises for this to make a bit more sense. although i see the point about when being uneeded. I am using load to inject a bunch of html in the index.html on click

Comment: Ok, will give your edit a shot.

Comment: This did the trick (I think, no TDD here so 100 clicks and no fail, I count that as a passed test :). I was using callback after $('.apple_device').load('html/macbook.html'); callback(); rather than after the html string before your comment. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @PurpleSkyz No, that's not right. If you're using `.load(...); callback()`, then you're invoking `callback` immediately and not actually waiting for the `load` to finish. At that point, you might as well not use the callback at all, it **serves no purpose** unless you use `load(url, callback)`.

Comment: Thats what I was saying, before you gave me the correct answer, i was invoking immediately.

Comment: Ah, ok. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from `loadMacBook` and `browser`.

Comment: Good find. Easy to gloss over something like that when you spend your day writing CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery promises is the way to go for this. You need to return promises for the called methods and then you can apply then to it. 
So it will look something like this

$.when(method returning promise).then(callback).always(alwaysExecutes).

Created a sample fiddle for the same which may help you bit about learning promises.

https://jsfiddle.net/gnekLssh/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function success(data){
   alert('I am inside success');
   alert(data);
 }

 function failure(data){
   alert('I am inside failure');
   alert(data);
 }

  function always(){
    alert('I will always be called')
  }

  function demoPromise(){
                                          $.when(showPromiseSuccessMagic(true)).then(success,failure).always(always);
//$.when(showPromiseSuccessMagic(false)).then(success, failure).always(always);


  }


  function showPromiseSuccessMagic(isSuccess){
        alert('Inside showPromise');
      var deferred = $.Deferred();

      if(isSuccess){
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert('Starting countdown now');
           for(var counter =0; counter <10; counter ++){
            $("#counter").append(counter);
           alert(counter);
           if(counter == 9){
                alert('Now counter will stop and promise will resolve');
                            deferred.resolve('Resolved value goes here');

             }

           }

       }
      , 2000);
    }else{
      deferred.reject('Rejected Value goes here');
     }
  return deferred.promise();

 }

 function showPromiseFailureMagic(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
     deferred.reject('Rejected promise');
     return deferred.promise();

   }

  demoPromise();

});

<div id ="counter"></div>
```

Hope this be of some help

Happy Learning :)